# How do smallint, integer, word and byte save data?

Tags: integer, int, byte, cpu-word

I got this thing for an  exam where I have to choose which applies

1. The decimal number 146 is saved in the computer as "10010010"
2. The decimal number 38,069 is saved in the computer as "1001010010110101"
3. The decimal number -95 is saved in the computer as "10100001"
4. The decimal number -32,695 is saved in the computer as "1000000001001001"

And I have to choose between smallint, integer, word and byte.

Any answers and reasons as to why??

Answer (score 2):

So, without context (what language you're working with, in particular), it's difficult to get a definitive answer, but generally speaking, Integer types are signed, but the length varies based on the language, and word/byte are unsigned.

Based on that, and assuming there is exactly one answer per entry, I'd suggest:

1) Byte - 8 bits, unsigned, range 0 to 255

2) Word - 16 bits, unsigned, range 0 to 65535

3) Smallint - 8 bits, signed, range -128 to 127

4) Int - 16 bits, signed, range -32768 to 32767

Answer (score 1):

It's depending af several things *(language, OS, Signed, Unsigned, Fixed point, Floating point...)*

**For integer** : Int precision < Long precision

**For float** : Float precison < Double precision

**For Decimal** : depending precision and scale.

For computer Decimal are not Float.

It's a very large subject

*At the end number can be stored in binary format (more compact and efficient) and can also stored in text format (ex xml, json, csv...)*

Answer (score 1):

1. 146: unsigned byte or smallint

   - Unsigned bytes go from 0-255 but signed bytes go from -127 to 127
   - You are given eight bits but you might assume the msb are suppressed
2. 38,069: unsigned smallint or integer

   - Unsigned smallint (shorts) go from 0-65,535 but signed smallints go from -32,767 to 32,767
3. -95: has to be a **signed byte**

   - You know this because the msb is 1, therefore you can identify what the msb is.  i.e. no suppressed zeros here.
4. -32,695: has to be a **signed smallint**

   - Same reasons as (3), you can identify the sign bit, so you know where the msb is

Comment: This is the correct Answer. I wonder if Asker even knows what an MSB is.